# Whats does adding user to sudoer file do?

Tags: linux

I am trying to run a command that needs to write to the / folder. I added myself as user to sudoers file using sudo visudo. Added the following line at the end of file.

```
yedg  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

The command still fails complaining about permissions. Now this makes me wonder does adding to sudoers file allow me to run as root or does it give me privileges similar to root? Looks like the former. Am I right or did I miss something?

Comment: May help http://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo

Comment: So looks like it only allows me to run as root. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you are added to sudoers file, you have permission to execute commands as root through `sudo` command.

Something like this:

```
sudo apt-get install skype
sudo rm -rf protectedDirectory
```

Actually sudo means substitute user do.